# unexpected results with word2vec algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, word2vec

I implemented word2vec in c++.
I found the original syntax to be unclear, so I figured I'd re-implement it, using all the benefits of c++ (std::map, std::vector, etc)

This is the method that actually gets called every time a sample is trained (l1 denotes the index of the first word, l2 the index of the second word, label indicates whether it is a positive or negative sample, and neu1e acts as the accumulator for the gradient)

```
void train(int l1, int l2, double label, std::vector<double>& neu1e)
{
        // Calculate the dot-product between the input words weights (in 
        // syn0) and the output word's weights (in syn1neg).
        auto f = 0.0;

        for (int c = 0; c < m__numberOfFeatures; c++) 
            f += syn0[l1][c] * syn1neg[l2][c];

      // This block does two things:
      //   1. Calculates the output of the network for this training
      //      pair, using the expTable to evaluate the output layer
      //      activation function.
      //   2. Calculate the error at the output, stored in 'g', by
      //      subtracting the network output from the desired output, 
      //      and finally multiply this by the learning rate.
      auto z = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-f));
      auto g = m_learningRate * (label - z);

      // Multiply the error by the output layer weights.
      // (I think this is the gradient calculation?)
      // Accumulate these gradients over all of the negative samples.
      for (int c = 0; c < m__numberOfFeatures; c++) 
        neu1e[c] += (g * syn1neg[l2][c]);    

      // Update the output layer weights by multiplying the output error
      // by the hidden layer weights.
      for (int c = 0; c < m__numberOfFeatures; c++) 
        syn1neg[l2][c] += g * syn0[l1][c];         
}
```

This method gets called by

```
void train(const std::string& s0, const std::string& s1, bool isPositive, std::vector<double>& neu1e)
    {
        auto l1 = m_wordIDs.find(s0) != m_wordIDs.end() ? m_wordIDs[s0] : -1;
        auto l2 = m_wordIDs.find(s1) != m_wordIDs.end() ? m_wordIDs[s1] : -1;
        if(l1 == -1 || l2 == -1)
            return;

        train(l1, l2, isPositive ? 1 : 0, neu1e);
    }
```

which in turn gets called by the main training method.

Full code can be found at

https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ml/tree/master/word2vec

With complete example at

https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ml/blob/master/main/example_8.hpp

When I run this algorithm, the top 10 words 'closest' to `father` are:

> father
>   Khan
>   Shah
>   forgetful
>   Miami
>   rash
>   symptoms
>   Funeral
>   Indianapolis
>   impressed

This the method to calculate the nearest words:

```
std::vector<std::string> nearest(const std::string& s, int k) const
    {
        // calculate distance
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, double>> tmp;
        for(auto &t : m_unigramFrequency)
        {
            tmp.push_back(std::make_tuple(t.first, distance(t.first, s)));
        }

        // sort
        std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), [](const std::tuple<std::string, double>& t0, const std::tuple<std::string, double>& t1)
        {
            return std::get<1>(t0) < std::get<1>(t1);
        });

        // take top k
        std::vector<std::string> out;
        for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
            out.push_back(std::get<0>(tmp[tmp.size() - 1 - i]));
        }

        // return
        return out;
    }
```

Which seems weird.
Is something wrong with my algorithm?

Comment: Unless there is a [mcve] there is little we can do to help. I doubt anyone will go through some 3rd party code to find a bug. Please provide a mcve.

Comment: BTW, if you want "all the benefits of C++", you should use algorithms such as [std::inner_product](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product).

Comment: Have you run a comparison against another word2vec algorithm?

Comment: @ron I did not include all the code since that would be between 200 and 300 lines. I thought 'nobody is going to want to read that'

Comment: @JorisSchellekens You are right to assume that. Try to re-structure the problem and provide a chunk of code that passes for [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you get "nearest" words (not farest)?

```
        ...
        // take top k
        std::vector<std::string> out;
        for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
        {
            out.push_back(std::get<0>(tmp[tmp.size() - 1 - i]));
        }
        ...
```

Comment: I assume the distance is the cosine-similarity distance. And I create tuples of word, distance. And then sort them on the second part of the tuple.

Comment: "nearest" means **minimum** distance? You sort in ascending order.

Comment: I updated the code to show the calculation of the nearest words.